# A pretrained model for mathematical equations characters detection

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, tensorflow, object-detection

I am working on a project to convert equations to LaTeX code. After segmenting out the characters, I got stuck on the detection part and was looking for some pre-trained model that could detect characters of the equation for later conversion to LaTeX. Is there any such pre-trained model available on the internet that could be used in Python to identify characters. If not then can somebody share some source to find a dataset to train such kind of model in Keras?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this detection problem using images of equations as input or raw text?